# Does A dataTable.Rows.Count Get Evaluated On Each Loop?

Tags: c#

I just wonder if I do something like

for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)

Does array.Count get revaluated on each iteration?

The reason I ask is becuase if I delete rows from that datatable will that cause problems?

Comment: you shouldn't be changing the iterated container anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does get evaluated each time, but you **really** shouldn't be changing the number of elements you are iterating through like that.